# UNNEST error with Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am uisng Google BigQuery with standard SQL and I am stuck.

The error is:

> Values referenced in UNNEST must be arrays. UNNEST contains expression of type STRING at [1:1155]

The query is:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_first_touch_timestamp) AS count,
  event_date AS dt
FROM 
  `analytics_173262434.events_20*` AS t
CROSS JOIN 
  UNNEST(event_date) AS event
WHERE
  PARSE_DATE('%y%m%d', _table_suffix) 
    BETWEEN DATE_SUB(current_date(), INTERVAL 23 DAY)
      AND DATE_SUB(current_date(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY event_date
```

Comment: Can you share more info abut the table schema and an example of the input data and the expected output?

Comment: That query is malformed, as you cannot unnest event_date which is a String. First define what you wanted to achieve.